# Angular2 - Pushing data to an array w/ interface

Tags: angular

I have a component that receives data from a service via `subscribe`. I am storing this data as an `array` and then using `*ngFor` to loop over it and display the results in a table.

The problem is, instead of overwriting this array each time the button is clicked, I only want to push to it so that it doesn't wipe out the data already being displayed on the page.

**Component:**

```
import { ImportResults } from '../shared/mass.interface';
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MassEmpService } from '../shared/mass.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee-selection',
    templateUrl: './employee-selection.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./employee-selection.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

    // Define our search results
    public searchResults: ImportResults[];

    constructor(
        private _massEmpService: MassEmpService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this._massEmpService.importedResults.subscribe(
            data => this.searchResults = data
        );

    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { FrameworkService } from '@aps/framework';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class MassEmpService {

    // API URL
    baseUrl = 'https://internal-site/api';

    // Define the token headers for the service calls
    headers: Headers = new Headers({
        "Authorization": this._frameworkService.getSessionInfo().token
    });

    // Create a subject to observe the results and changes over time
    public importedResults = new Subject<any>();

    constructor(
        private _http: Http,
        private _frameworkService: FrameworkService
    ) { }

    // Given a dataset, return the users based on data points submitted
    processImport(dataType, dataSet): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchEmployeesFromImport', { "dataType": dataType, "data": dataSet }, { "headers": this.headers })
            .map((result: Response) => result.json())
            .share()
            .catch(this.handleError);
    };

    // Pass the data received from the import process through our subject to observe
    fetchImportedResults(data){
        this.importedResults.next(data);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server Issue');
    }

}
```

**The Problem**

In the component, I am setting `this.searchResults` to the results that are fetched. Each time that is called, it is just overwriting the results. I need this data to be pushed to the array if it doesn't already exist in there instead of overwriting each time.

**What I Tried**

I tried to initialize the array by doing `public searchResults: ImportResults[] = [];` and then using `data => this.searchResults.push(data)`. While this doesn't throw an error, my table that is being looped over no longer renders the data. I believe this is due to it now being inside of another array.

*This is what my data looks like before I try to use PUSH. I am guessing that when I push to it, its changing the structure so the `*ngFor` is now not looping correctly.*
[image: This is what my data looks like before I try to use PUSH]

Comment: Where do you update / push the data in your code? What does your html look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are pushing the whole array into the results array instead of the individual objects. Try using the spread operator in combination with `push` to add the new items to the array like this:

```js
data => this.searchResults.push(...data)
```

Comment: Jeez, something so simple :x - appreciate you pointing it out, i was over thinking this one. Will accept shortly!

Comment: How can i push on specific length?

Comment: @ER.SHASHITIWARI perhaps you are looking for the `fill` function? So `new Array(5).fill(1)` creates an array of length 5 that is filled with `1`s.